# Django and SQL Server 2005 - Zombie status?

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, django-mssql

I'm using Django 1.2 and [django-mssql](http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/).

While performing the following

```
for unicorn in Unicorn.objects.all():
    print unicorn.color
```

I'm getting the following error at around the 100th iteration:

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft SQL Server Nativ
>   e Client 10.0', u'The object is in a zombie state. An object may enter a zombie
>   state when either ITransaction::Commit or ITransaction::Abort is called, or when
>    a storage object was created and not yet released.', None, 0, -2147418113), Non
>   e)

---

**Any idea?** This is really bugging me... starting to hate the whole Windows Server world... :(

Comment: COM error is not a joke (I'm a former DirectX developer, I see COM errors in my nightmares), and COM error + zombie is a real Resident Evil :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it by forcing the full QuerySet to be retrieved before using it in the for loop.
So, try this:

```
for unicorn in list(Unicorn.objects.all()):
    print unicorn.color
```

Comment: @RadiantHex: Did you find it useful? Have you found the cause of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set 'can_use_chunked_read = True' in base.DatabaseFeature:

sqlserver_ado/base.py: 16

```
class DatabaseFeatures(BaseDatabaseFeatures):
    uses_custom_query_class = True
    can_use_chunked_reads = False
```

I just set it and the error has gone away.
Let me know if it solves your problem too.